# How to use custom tokens in view header Drupal 8

Tags: views

I make custom token which i use in view filter but now i want to use in view header.The custom token doesn't show in view header Global: Unfiltered text (Global: Unfiltered text) or how i make "Available global token replacements" to use in view header Global: Unfiltered text (Global: Unfiltered text). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One possible soliton is to simply when declaring your custom tokens in hook_token_info()

use `$info['tokens']['view']`

Ex:

```
$info['tokens'] = [
    'view' => [
       'my-custom-token' => [
          'name' => t('Custom Token'),
          'description' => t('A custom token I created.'),
       ],
       // 'my-second-custom-token' => [...
    ],
];
```